# Julia convention for optional arguments

Tags: julia

Say I have a function such as `f(x,y)` but the `y` parameter is optional. What is the preferred way to set `y` as an optional argument? One option that works for me:

```
function f(x, y=nothing)
    # do stuff 
    if y == nothing
        # do stuff
    else
        # do stuff
    end
    # do stuff
end
```

But is this the preferred way? I can't set `y` to a single default value to use in calculation, as there are a number of calculations that are done differently when `y` is nothing. I could also just have separate functions `f(x)` and `f(x,y)` but that seems like too much code duplication.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is fine. Note that optional arguments cause dispatch. This means that the `if y == nothing` (or equivalently, `if typeof(y) <: Void`), will actually compile away. You'll get two different functions which depend on whether the user gives a value or not. So in the end, the `if` statement compiles away and it's perfectly efficient to do this.

I will note that the same is not currently true for keyword arguments.

Another way to do this is to have two methods:

```
f(x)
```

and

```
f(x,y)
```

Whether two methods is nicer than 1 method with an `if` depends on the problem. Since the `if` will compile away using type information, there's no difference between these two approaches other than code organization.

Comment: Thanks! Is your version of checking whether y is nothing better/the preferred way?

Comment: I believe `y == nothing` is the one case where checking values will compile away, because the only way to be `nothing` is to have `typeof(y) <: Void`. But if you just always use type checks, you can know that in type-stable functions that they will compile away. That fact is pretty safe. This is because type stable functions for sure will always know types, but not necessarily values. `Void` is different though

Comment: I'm sure this way is fine, but the question was what is the preferred way, and the preferred way is normally (but not always) to define two separate methods `f(x)` and `f(x, y)`. Particularly if it makes the code cleaner.

Comment: It doesn't always make it cleaner, not if you have some shared "preamble" and "postamble" like in the op. You can create "inner functions" for those two parts, and thus you have two functions which duplicate the top and bottom function calls with something different in the middle. But at that point I am not convinced that two functions is objectively simpler.

Comment: A common example: inside the function you use `y` to set a few constants, with a default if the user doesn't set anything. 99% of the other code is the same, just this conditional. Is it really better to move all the code around and refactor to four functions (two top level, two inside) just for that?

Comment: Clearly not. But since Julia generally is good for concise functions/methods, I think that you very often end up with separate methods, and most of the examples I've seen emphasize multiple methods over input checking. Perhaps it would be good to at least mention this very common approach?